# Read partial of text file using PHP

Tags: php, regex, file-io

I want to implement a flat file blogging system. I would like the blog to load a bunch text files as it's articles, the text file format looks like this

```
{
    "title": "Hangout with friends",
    "slug": "handout-with-friends",
    "date": "06-05-2012",
    "category": "General",
    "tag": "Lifestyle, Social",
    "author": "Someone"
}

### Introduction

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

### Whatever 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

### Whatever 2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

There are 2 parts in the article text files, the first part is for the meta, and the second is for the content.

When the blog is loaded, I **only** want the **first part**, so I can then manipulate an array for the some menu and the article list.

This is the coding I'm using right now.

```
private function createArticleFromHeader($filelist) {

        $articles = array();

        foreach($filelist as $filename) {
            $header = array();

            $handle = fopen($header_file, 'r');

            $raw = preg_replace("/" . PHP_EOL. "{2,}/", PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, stream_get_contents($handle));

            $sections = explode( PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $raw);

            $meta = json_decode(array_shift($sections), true);

            $articles[] = new Article($meta);
        }

        return $articles;
    }
```

I have no problems performing with this coding, but I'm looking for a **cheap process** to to **only load the first part** instead of load the entire file then explode it later as in my coding, as the blog may deal with a hundred of articles. I don't mind if I have to **put some special markup** into the file to separate it's meta and content.

Please help.

Comment: Surely a database (even SQLite) would be a saner approach than a text file based solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [`fgets`](http://php.net/fgets) function is designed to read one line at a time from a file handle.
Since you don't mind adding something to the file, if you put a separator like `##########` (or something else that is not likely to be found in your file), it is easy to detect it.

Your example would be:

```
{
    "title": "Hangout with friends",
    "slug": "handout-with-friends",
    "date": "06-05-2012",
    "category": "General",
    "tag": "Lifestyle, Social",
    "author": "Someone"
}
##########
### Introduction

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
```

And the code to read it would look something like this:

```
private function createArticleFromHeader($filelist) {

    $articles = array();

    foreach($filelist as $filename) {
        $header = array();

        $handle = fopen($header_file, 'r');
        $raw = "";
        while (($buffer = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if (trim($buffer) == "##########") {
                break;
            }
            $raw .= $buffer;
        }
        $raw = preg_replace("/" . PHP_EOL. "{2,}/", PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $raw);

        $meta = json_decode($raw, true);

        $articles[] = new Article($meta);
    }

    return $articles;
}
```

You should also close your file handles if you really expect to be handling so many at once, otherwise you may run out of memory faster than you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your meta data doesn't span across one block of 8192 bytes, you could use this:

```
$meta = json_decode(strtok(
    file_get_contents($filename, false, null, 0, 8192), 
    PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL
), true);
```